# How to load existing coefficients into sklearn SVM classifier?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

I trained a SVM classifier using `sklearn.svm.SVC`, and stored the weights (coefficients). Then I loaded them and tried to inject them into a new instance of `sklearn.svm.SVC`, but could not do it because it seems that the attribute `coef_` is read only..

```py
from sklearn import svm
import pickle

modelSVM = svm.SVC(kernel='linear')
weights = pickle.load(open(weights_path, 'rb'))

modelSVM.coef_ = weights
```

I expect to have a model with the weights I loaded as new coefficients, but I get this message:

```
AttributeError: 'SVC' object has no attribute 'dual_coef_'
```

Which might be due to the fact that `coef_` is not the only field needed by the classifier. So I tried to train and then clone the classifier before injecting weights:

```py
modelSVM.fit(X, labels)
modelSVM = clone(modelSVM)
modelSVM.coef_ = weights
```

It gives the output:

```
"Exception has occurred: AttributeError
can't set attribute"
```

Comment: As per the scikit learn [documentation][1]

`coef_` is a readonly property derived from `raw_coef_` that follows the internal memory layout of liblinear.

So, I am afraid that you cannot set it directly.


  [1]: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of loading the weights, which is not possible as pointed out by *@Mechanic* in the comments. You can try to save the model and load the model back. Please refer to [this link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html).